# How to insert Array[Byte] into binary datatype column with slick and mariadb?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, mariadb, slick

I attempted to insert Array[Byte] into binary datatype colunm with scala and play framework and slick on MariaDB.
However, I got this error and the data wasn't inserted.

```
Execution exception
[MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\x85\x09\x9B\x08%B...' for column 'userID' at row 1]
```

The data is UUID that use java.util.UUID.
The conversion UUID to Array[Byte] is implemented by UUIDHelper.scala that is [this code](http://nineofclouds.blogspot.jp/2013/04/storing-uuids-with-anorm.html).

How can I insert Array[Byte] data to database?

My environment is this.

Database:

```
MariaDB 10.1.16

MariaDB [test]> show full columns from user;
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field     | Type         | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| userID    | binary(16)   | NULL            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| firstName | varchar(254) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| lastName  | varchar(254) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| fullName  | varchar(254) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| email     | varchar(254) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| avatarURL | varchar(254) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

userID is colunm for UUID.

play-slick configuration:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

play and scala version:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "3.0.2",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0-1",
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.0.0",
  "net.ceedubs" %% "ficus" % "1.1.2",
  "com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap3" % "0.4.4-P24",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-testkit" % "3.0.2" % "test",
  specs2 % Test,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.0.1",
  //"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.188",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.39",
  cache,
  evolutions,
  filters
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Eventually, I looked at completely other table. In the another table, that has also userID, the data type of userID was VARCHAR(254). I fixed this data type to BINARY(16) and the data was inserted into database with Array[Byte] on scala + slick. Additionally, the data could be inserted directly to MariaDB with type of java.util.UUID.

I'm sorry for troubling you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the byte array being used for the UUID?  If so, I suggest you generate the hex of the UUID, then

```
INSERT ... (uuid, ...)
    VALUES
    (UNHEX(?), ...)
```

(I don't know the correct syntax for substitution in Slick.)

As a side note, [*UUIDs are terrible for scaling*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/).

**More**

That is, do *not* try to store what you are calling "characters" into `binary(16)`.  Only "bytes" ("BLOB", not "CLOB") stuff should be stored in `BINARY`.

Comment: Relying on [this document](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.1/schemas.html?highlight=uuid), I think we can use Array[Byte] (and java.util.UUID).
However, I got the above error when I used Array[Byte] and java.util.UUID.